# Passing subroutines/functions through parameters

Tags: function, programming-languages, theory, parameter-passing

I am just wondering what the advantages are to languages that allow functions to be passed through parameters?  And hopefully an couple examples to go with this.

What popular programming languages allow this?

Comment: The second question is best answered by [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) or [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/First-class_functions). Also, are you interested in e.g. function pointers (you can pass those around as parameters, but most languages allow much more) too, or advantages of functions as first-class values in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose I have a collection of objects, and I want to sort them based on some criteria.

If I can pass a function to a function, it's easy:

```
collection.sort((a, b) => a.SomeProperty.compareTo(b.SomeProperty));
```

If I can't, then in order to do something like this I basically have to reimplement the sorting algorithm each time I want to sort based on different criteria.

Comment: Note that even C's function pointers can do this (although not generic or type-safe). Anonymous functions, as in this example, are related but something different.

Comment: The anonymous function isn't strictly necessary to the example. The same thing can be somewhat accomplished with the ability to pass named functions around, even if it means you have to define them somewhere away from where they are used. The big point is that in languages like Java that don't let you pass functions as arguments, you have to do some pretty ugly hacks (like wrapping it up in a class just so you can pass it as an argument) just to get the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is that you can parametrize functions over things that aren't easily expressed as plain values.

For example if you want to find an item which satisfies a certain predicate in a collection, or you want to find out whether all items in a collection satisfy a predicate, the predicate is most naturally expressed as a function from the element type to bool.

Another really common example is a sorting function which takes a comparison function as its argument, so the elements of a collection can be sorted by a custom sort key.

Of course in languages that don't allow functions as arguments, but which do have an object system (read: in java), you can work around this by using an object which implements a certain interface to the sorting function.

> What popular programming languages allow [passing functions as arguments]?

C, C++, C#, Objective C, Python, Ruby, Perl, PHP, Javascript, and basically all functional or functionalish languages.

It should be noted that C and C++ (before C++0x), unlike the other languages in the list, don't have closures.

Comment: C++0x adds anonymous functions and closures. But this question isn't about closures.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of being able to pass functions to other functions is that it allows you to write cleaner, more general code.  For instance, consider a reasonably realistic function which sums all the numbers in a list:

```
sum []     = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

This is in Haskell syntax, which may be unfamiliar to you; the two lines define two different cases, depending on whether the input is an empty list, in which case the sum is zero, or it's `x` prepended to the list `xs`, in which case the sum is `x` plus the sum of `xs`.  In a more traditional language (not any one in particular), you'd have

```
function sum(xs) {
  var total = 0
  for x in xs {
    total = x + total
  }
  return total
}
```

Now, suppose we want to find the product of the numbers in a list, instead:

```
product []     = 1
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

In a traditional language, it'd look more like

```
function product(xs) {
  var total = 1
  for x in xs {
    total = x * total
  }
  return total
}
```

Interestingly, these two functions look pretty much the same.  The only difference is that `0` is replaced with `1`, and `+` is replaced with `*`.  And indeed, it turns out that we can generalize both `sum` and `+`:

```
foldr f i []     = i
foldr f i (x:xs) = f x (foldr f i xs)
```

Here, `foldr` takes three arguments: a two-argument function `f`, a constant `i`, and a list.  If the list is empty, we return the constant (*e.g.*, `sum [] = 0`); otherwise, we apply the function to (a) the first element of the list, and (b) the result of folding the rest of the list.  In a more traditional language, this'd look something like

```
function foldr(f,i,xs)
  var result = i
  for x in xs {
    result = f(x, result)
  }
  return result
}
```

This means that we can simplify `sum` and `product` to simply

```
sum     = foldr (+) 0
product = foldr (*) 1
```

(Here, `(+)` and `(*)` are two-argument functions which add and multiply their arguments, respectively.)  You can't do this without first-class functions.  (The other thing I'm doing is leaving off the last argument; this is called currying, and is rather handy.  The idea is that if I don't give `foldr` all its arguments, it returns a function which is expecting the rest of them.  But if you find it confusing, imagine the definitions say `sum xs = foldr (+) 0 xs`.)

But here's where things can get more interesting.  Suppose you have a list of numbers, and you want to compute the square of every number in the list:

```
squares []     = []
squares (x:xs) = (x^2) : squares xs

function squares(xs) {
  var result = []
  for x in xs {
    result = result ++ [x^2]
  }
  return result
}
```

But this is clearly abstractable: almost exactly the same code would work if you wanted to negate every element of your list, or if you had a list of emails and wanted to get the senders, or whatever.  So, we abstract:

```
map f []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs

function map(f,xs) {
  var result = []
  for x in xs {
    result = result ++ [f(x)]
  }
  return result
}

squares      = map (^2) # (^2) is the function which squares its argument.
negations    = map negate
emailSenders = map getSender
```

But interestingly enough, we can also implement `map` in terms of our previous `foldr`.  First, we need to define function composition, `.`:

```
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

This says the composition of `f` and `g` is a new anonymous function of one argument, which itself applies `g` to `x` and `f` to the result.  And so now, we can define `map`:

```
map f = foldr ((:) . f) []
```

Here, `(:)` is the function which takes an element and a list, and returns that element prepended to the list.  `(:) . f` is the same as `\x -> (:) (f x)`, which (under the currying rule I mentioned) is the same as `\x xs -> f x : xs`.  In other words, at each step of the fold, prepend `f x` to what we have so far.  (This doesn't gives us the reverse of `map` because `foldr` works "inside-out", as it were.)

This definition of `map` uses the higher-order function `.` to construct the function it passes to `foldr`.  So many functions are being passed as parameters!  And this lets us do things like write

```
f &&& g = \x -> (f x, g x)
```

And then use that to write

```
sendersAndRecipients = map (getSender &&& getRecipient) . fetchEmails
```

You gain a lot of power by being able to treat functions as values.  You can write generic procedures like `map` or `&&&`, which allow you to write concise but readable code later.  Passing around functions also comes in handy for callbacks: `sendMessage(theMessage,fn)`, where `fn` is a function to be run when a response is received.  It's just a very natural way to work.

As for what languages support this: honestly, Wikipedia'd know better than I would.  But I'll give it a shot.  C and C++ do, sort of: you can't write functions in-line, but you can pass function pointers around.  It's not terribly common in either language though (even less in C).  Any OO language can, if you define a class which has a single method which is the function you want, but this is terribly clunky.  Nevertheless, this is what Java does.  C#, on the other hand, actually has functions which can be passed as parameters.  Ruby (which also has "blocks", which are a special syntax for certain use cases), Python, Perl, and JavaScript all support passing functions around, as does every functional programming language: the Lisps (Scheme, Common Lisp, Clojure, …); the ML family (SML, OCaml, …); Haskell (which could be lumped in with the ML family); Scala; and others.  It's a useful feature, so it's not surprising to see it so wide-spread.